# How to label points?

Tags: matlab, matrix, label, points

I try to label 70 points (which can be seen as nodes) whose coordinates are contained in a matrix with two columns. In labelize I mean to appropriate to each one a number and for example to obtain a matrix with three columns where the first two are always the coordinates and the third the label

I saw in the doc `labelnode` and `graph` for example but I do not have the right version of matlab for these functions (I use R2015a). And `labelmatrix` or `bwlabel` transforms my matrix of coordinates into a matrix of 1.

How can I do ?

```
317 948
319 935
320 969
320 969
326 916
```

Comment: Do you mean something like [text](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html)? Can you please add a code sample to your question (3 points example should be enough)?

Comment: yes I can : first column is X and second Y.  I would like a label for each line

Comment: Do the labels have to be strings? Or numbers are fine? Do they have to be unique and increasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if I got your problem right. For what I understood, you can simply add a column of unique numbers to your data. If we say your data is stored in matrix `X`, you can do:

```
labels = 1:size(X,1); % generate a vector of integers from 1 to number of rows of X
X = [X, labels']; % concatenate the matrix X and the vector of labels

% X = [ 317 948 1
%       319 935 2
%       320 969 3
%       320 969 4
%       326 916 5
%       .........]
```

If instead you want **the same** label for points with the same coordinates, you can use `unique` to generate those labels:

```
[~, ~, labels] = unique(X, 'rows');
X = [X, labels];


% X = [ 317 948 1
%       319 935 2
%       320 969 3
%       320 969 3
%       326 916 4
%       .........]
```

Comment: Your second solution is the right solution but with X = [X, labels] and not X = [X, labels' ]. Thanks :-D

Comment: Yeah, my mistake! Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.

1. Simply use numeric array with numeric labels. You can easily append this to existing table.

   ```
   arr(:,3) = labels;
   ```
2. You can use cell array, 1 and 2 would be numbers and 3 would be then string for label.

   ```
   arrWL = cell(size(arr,1), 3);
   arrWL{:,1:2} = arr;
   arrWL{:,3} = labels;
   ```
3. You can also use `table` to label rows and columns.

   ```
   X = arr(:,1);
   Y = arr(:,2);
   arrWL = table(X, Y, 'RowNames', labels);
   ```
4. Put both data and labels together as separate entries in a cell array (with 2 elements).

   ```
   arrWL = {arr, labels};
   ```

I could probably think of some other options if none of these are suitable.

Now, to generate unique numbers for labels, use:

```
[~,~,positions] = unique(arr, 'rows', 'stable'); 
% I prefer stable so the first point gets index 1 etc.
```